# Wrong formation of static links in template django

Tags: django, nginx, static, web-deployment, gunicorn

I deployed my Django app using nginx and works fine. But my images doesn't load in pages. Not is problem with static folder, because favicon and css and js files loaded sucessfully.

I take a look in a source code formed in webbrowser and i saw that the images have a '/' in the end of link. This is making the address invalid. If a remove manually the '/' i found the resource in site. But i don't know what is causing the insertion this caractere.

My sites-available file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico {access_log_off; log_not_found off;}
    location /static/ {
        root /home/pi/WebSite;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:home/pi/WebSite/Website.sock;
    }
}
```

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
```

My template file:

```
<div class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
   <img class="img-rounded img-responsive text-center" src = {% static 'img/sistema.png' %}/>
   <img class="img-rounded img-responsive text-center" src = {% static 'img/legenda.png' %}/>
</div>
```

In the source code of the site, the images appears:

```
<div class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
   <img class="img-rounded img-responsive text-center" src = /static/img/sistema.png/>
   <img class="img-rounded img-responsive text-center" src = /static/img/legenda.png/>
</div>
```

Any ideas, sugestions? 
Thanks a lot, i no more ideas

Comment: My bad..... i was using img html statement in wrong mode.
The img doesn't finish with '/>'.  Sorry

In development mode the page works fine rsrs.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `src = {% static 'img/sistema.png' %}`. This leads to invalid HTML. Instead you should have `src="{% static 'img/sistema.png' %}"`. That will mean that the browser will know that the `/` is not part of the images' URLs.